Playbook for checkpoint
I want to make some playbooks for checkpoint; My question is: for checkpoint is there a specific connection string from ansible?
`Procedure to generate database backup in Security Management Server:
$MDS_FWDIR/scripts/migrate_server import/export -v R81.10 -skip_upgrade_tools_check /path_to_file/export.tgz`
Regards;
I would like to be able to do without modules, since I use an offline installation

You can use match,search or regex to match strings against a substring.
Read more about this in official docs testing strings
Or if you need specific package(Nginx example) then
when: nginxVersion.stdout != 'nginx version: nginx/1.2.6'

will check if Nginx is not present on your server and install 1.2.6.
